# Erro no POST da API ao inserir objeto

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

Ola,

Estou tentando adicionar um objeto ao banco chamando minha API e recebo esse erro:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got NCLOB

Eu só queria uma ajuda de direcionamento, comentários de onde eu possa dar uma atenção mais reforçada, qualquer coisinha, estou aceitando achismo, porque eu realmente preciso resolver isso... Estou a quase 2 dias sem saber o que fazer... Não sei onde olhar...

Já verifiquei vaaarias vezes os tipos dos dados do objeto e do banco, estão iguais...

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost, Route("api/User/Atualizar/")]
public void Atualizar([FromBody] MeuObjeto model)
{
    var Repositorio = new Repositorio();
    Repositorio.Adicionar(model); // Erro ocorre aqui
}
```

**Edição**

Para fins de didática aqui, eu fiz o mais simples possível, conectando diretamente na `API`, portanto editei o post para facilitar na visualização...
Funciona da mesma forma e gera o mesmo erro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro não é na API em si (digamos assim), ele aconteceu no Oracle porque você tentou executar uma operação entre dois tipos de dados diferentes, mas os tipos de dados não são compatíveis.
Corrija a operação para que os tipos de dados sejam compatíveis. Você pode querer usar uma função de conversão como: TO_NUMBER.

Para uma [lista completa das funções do Oracle](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/index.php).

Comment: Eu teria que fazer isso pelo C#, acima usei o `Convert.ToInt64` para fazer a conversão de `string` para `long`, que nos outros inserts funciona, porem neste, como eu preciso passar pela chamada anterior ao controller, eu recebi esse erro...

Comment: Bom você consegue fazer um debug do tipo de dado que estão chegando no update desse endpoint? Talvez tenha que forçar mais algum casting em algum desses pontos, e onde você faz o update com a tabela, imagino que exista um SQL que recebe a variavel com os valores recebidos na API, TO_NUMBER lá nao resolveria?

Comment: Então, no debug, eu recebo os dados corretos, long e string... Eu não tenho acesso a essa parte do sistema, não conseguiria modificar isto que sugeriu... So tenho acesso a API...

Comment: Pedi auxilio do pessoal aqui, deram uma olhada em algumas dependencias e funcionou... Realmente estava conflitando uma classe com o que estava no banco... Agradeço